# CPU Mining on Private Peercoin network

Tags: bitcoin, bitcoind

I have setup a private Peercoin network with two nodes on virtual box. Both clients are able to connect and i am able to start a separate private blockchain.
I have started mining using the `setgenerate true`.

Now i want to achieve similar thing using the latest client. I am able to connect two nodes with no outside connections. Now i want to start mining just like the older version, but seems like they have removed the `setgenerate` command.

How can i start CPU mining on the new client?

Answer (score -1):

Get a mining program like cgminer that supports peercoin and supports talking to a local full node over RPC. Configure your mining program to talk to one of your clients.

Comment: When i run...
`cgminer -o http://192.168.56.101:2332 -u user -p password --btc-address PK8x3CDKyoCP8PuEHFF8zL7qRYiGgAj7v8`
i get error
`No Stratum, GBT or Solo support in pool 0 http://192.168.56.101:2332 unable to use`

Comment: Do you have "server=1 listen=1 daemon=1" in your client configuration? Do you have RPC set to allow a connection from whatever local IP address the mining machine has? Is cgminer using the write kernel, such as poclbm?

Comment: I tried all these, and also rechecked my source code and recompiled. But the error is still here..
`The requested URL returned error: 500 Internal Server Error`